# Unable to add objects which extend a JPanel to my JFrame class

Tags: object, jframe, components, jpanel

I'm working on a game and I'm trying to add a JPanel to the JFrame. I have a separate class which extends JPanel and I create a new object which again, extends JPanel.

However, I get this error: "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (mainMenu)" (mainMenu is the class which extends JPanel).

It suggests adding an argument to match 'add(Component, Object)'

I am at a loss in trying to fix this especially because later in my code, I use the same add argument to add an object whose class extends a JButton. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried creating a regular JPanel and adding that which worked.

(JFrame class)
    public class gardenRunner extends JFrame {

```
public static void run(String[] args)
{
     new gardenRunner()
}

public void gardenRunner()
{
     mainMenu m = new mainMenu();
     add(m);       <-- gives error
}
```

(JPanel class)
    public class mainMenu extends JPanel {

```
public mainMenu()
{
     super();
     setSize(60, 60);
}
```

I would expect this to add a JPanel to my JFrame but this results in an error.

Comment: In the first line of my code, I meant for that to be public static void main(String[] args) not public static void run(String[] args), sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, turns out Eclipse was acting a little buggy and this worked when I deleted my JPanel class and made a new one. Thanks again.